# Can't match on enum without using value

Tags: swift2

I've updated my project to use Swift 2. I've come across a fairly silly situation with switches. Here's a simple example.

```
enum X {
    case AsInt(Int)
    case AsBool(Bool)
}
g() -> X { 
    // ...
}
f() -> Bool {
    let local = g();
    switch local {
    case .AsInt(let x)
        return true;
    case .AsBool(let bool)
        return false;
    }
}
```

The Swift compiler complains (warning) that `x` is unused, which it is. It tells me to replace with `_`. Fine, I replaced it with `_`. Then the Swift compiler complains (warning) that the `let` binding binds no variables. Fine, I removed it. Then the Swift compiler throws an error complaining that the tuple pattern doesn't match.

How do you match on an enum without using the value or getting a bunch of pointless warnings/errrors whose recommended fix does not actually fix anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
func f() -> Bool {
    switch g() {
    case .AsInt:
        return true
    case .AsBool:
        return false
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh, you have to completely omit the brackets just because there's nothing in them? That's... completely unintuitive.